# Api to analyse complex graph

Tags: python, api, graph, social-networking

I am looking for an API (preferably in python) that could be used to analyze complex networks. Basically I want to find things like:

Average [shortest path](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shortest_path_problem),

[Degree distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Degree_distribution)

[Giant Component](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Giant_component)

local clustering coefficient, global clustering coefficient etc..

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest [Networkx](http://networkx.lanl.gov/) and [PyGraphViz](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pygraphviz). I've used them for a similar (but not as complex) graphing project in python and I love it.

Answer (score 0):

The boost graph library has [Python bindings](http://osl.iu.edu/~dgregor/bgl-python/).

Comment: True, but the man behind boost "no longer have time to maintain or support this library". Also I've heard that it's quite a pain to deal with.

Answer (score 0):

I've used [igraph](http://igraph.sourceforge.net/) on Linux. It started to grind on 64k nodes but that graph was becoming unwieldy any way.

Not sure about performance next to PyGraphViz but now you have a plenty of options.